# List of instruments for Sound

Tags: sound

I am programming a littele piece of music using Sound[] and I have used sound primitives like "Violin", "Piano", "Organ".

Can you help me to find a complete list of these primitives?

Comment: You can find a longer list in the Details section of the [documentation for `SoundNote`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SoundNote.html).

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks a lot for the hint.